# VBA extremely slow closing read-only workbook (after copy worksheets)

Tags: excel, vba

After copying a worksheet (~300K Cells) from a source workbook in *read only* mode, to `Thisworkbook`, the `Workbook.Close False` function gets a delay of **1 minute**.

I have added a function that copies in several batches of about 50K Cells per loop, although I do not use the *Clipboard* in that particular case (for `Formulas`).

I have clean completely up the Clipboard at several points of the code.

However the code still seems to have some **delay issue** when **closing** the **source workbook**. I copy here a summary of the code creating the issue:

```
' Source: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Sub ClearClipboard()
 OpenClipboard (0&)
 EmptyClipboard
 CloseClipboard
End Sub

' Function with part of the code, to reflect the idea
Public Sub Main()
 Set wbSource = Application.Workbooks.Open(strFile, ReadOnly:=True)
 set wsSource = wbSource.WorkSheets("some worksheet")
 Set rnSource = wsSource.UsedRange
 Set rnSource = wsSource.Range("A1", rnSource.rows(rnSource.rows.Count).Columns(rnSource.Columns.Count).Address(False, False))

 Set wsDest = Thisworkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Thisworkbook.Worksheets(Thisworkbook.Sheets.Count))
 rnDest.Name = rnSource.Name
 Set rnDest = wsDest.Range(rnSource.Address(False, False))

 rnSource.Copy: rnDest.Activate
 rnDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

 'rnDest.Formula = rnSource.Formula ' for big datasets, better to launch batches of 16K cells
 rngBatchCopyFormulas rnSource, rnDest ' for big datasets, better to launch batches of 16K cells
 rnDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
 rnDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats ' (borders, colors, etc)
 rnDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
 rnDest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
 wsCopyButtons wsSource, wsDest

 ClearClipboard ' this does not seem to solve the delay when closing
 wbSource.Close False ' 1 minute to complete this action
End Sub
```

Any other ideas?

**EDIT**:

I think this has to do with memory usage... I have batched all the copy pastes with the following function, but still having the delay issue on `close` of source workbook:

```
Public Function rngBatchCopy(rnSource As Range, rnDest As Range, Optional maxTaskCells As Long = 50000, _
    Optional rngLibConf As RangeLibConf = Nothing) As Boolean
Dim rnSCurr As Range, rnDCurr As Range
Dim rnSRow As Range, rnDRow As Range
Dim lngTotalCells As Long, lngRows As Long, lngColumns As Long
Dim lngLoops As Long, lngRowsLoop As Long, lngRowsCurrLoop As Long
Dim lngCurrRow As Long, lngRestRows As Long

 On Error GoTo rngBatchCopyErr
 rngBatchCopy = False

 If (rnSource Is Nothing) Or (rnDest Is Nothing) Then Exit Function
 If rngLibConf Is Nothing Then Set rngLibConf = New RangeLibConf

 lngColumns = rnSource.Columns.Count: lngRows = rnSource.rows.Count
 lngTotalCells = lngColumns * lngRows 'rnsource.Cells.Count
 lngLoops = Round(lngTotalCells / maxTaskCells) - 1
 lngRowsLoop = IIf(maxTaskCells <= lngColumns, 1, Int(maxTaskCells / lngColumns))

 lngCurrRow = 1: lngRestRows = lngRows
 Do While (lngCurrRow <= lngRows) 'And (lngRestRows > 0)
    lngRowsCurrLoop = IIf(lngRowsLoop < lngRestRows, lngRowsLoop, lngRestRows)
    Set rnSRow = rnSource.rows(lngCurrRow)
    Set rnSCurr = rnSRow.Resize(lngRowsCurrLoop)
    Set rnDRow = rnDest.rows(lngCurrRow)
    Set rnDCurr = rnDRow.Resize(lngRowsCurrLoop)
    lngRestRows = lngRestRows - lngRowsCurrLoop: lngCurrRow = lngCurrRow + lngRowsCurrLoop

    rnSCurr.Copy
    With rngLibConf
        rnDCurr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats  ' to avoid Err: "To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size."
        'If .CopyFormulas Then rnDest.Formula = rnSource.Formula ' for big datasets, better to launch batches of 16K rows
        Application.CutCopyMode = False: Application.CutCopyMode = True
        rnSource.Copy
        If .CopyFormulas Then
            'rnSCurr.Copy: rnDCurr.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            rnDCurr.Formula = rnSCurr.Formula
            Application.CutCopyMode = False: Application.CutCopyMode = True
            rnSCurr.Copy
        End If
        If .CopyFormats Then
            rnDCurr.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
            rnDCurr.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats ' (borders, colors, etc)
            Application.CutCopyMode = False: Application.CutCopyMode = True
            rnSCurr.Copy
        End If
        If .CopyComments Then
            rnDCurr.PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
            Application.CutCopyMode = False: Application.CutCopyMode = True
            rnSCurr.Copy
        End If
        If .CopyValidation Then
            rnDCurr.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
            Application.CutCopyMode = False: Application.CutCopyMode = True
            rnSCurr.Copy
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False: Application.CutCopyMode = True
        ClearClipboard
    End With
 Loop
 rngBatchCopy = True
rngBatchCopyErr:
 'Application.CutCopyMode = False ' It cleans the clipboard partially
 ClearClipboard
End Function
```

Garbage collector related to `wbSource`?

**EDIT**:

It only happens when the source worksheet/range has formulas... Any ideas?

Comment: Does it take 1 minute to do the `wbSource.Close False` or does it take 1 minute to do that **and** the `End Sub`?

Comment: @YowE3K: at that specific point (when closing the source workbook: tested several times with several _break points_ in debug mode). **NOTE:** calculations at spreadsheet level are not enabled until at a later part of the code (not added here for simplicity reasons); I omitted a `rnDest.EnableCalculation = False` that also goes there... :|